# AngularJS Handling Relational JSONs

Tags: json, angularjs

I have a Codeigniter based REST API. I use it to extract my MySQL database as JSON and I want to use the JSON data in AngularJS.

In the database, I have two tables; Categories and Posts. I keep the category id of every post in Posts table. With PHP, I would just write a handler function that gets the id as a parameter and outputs the category name by connecting the database.

Now I would like to do a similar thing in AngularJS. I created two JSON Objects, one holds only birthday values and the other holds birthdays and names. I want to give the birthday as a parameter and output the name with ng-repeat. I tried to write a custom filter function, like so;

```
$scope.custom = function (user) {
  for (var i = 0; i < $scope.birthdays.length; i++) {
     if ($scope.birthdays[i].birthday == user.birthday) {
        return $scope.users[i].name;
     }
  }
};
```

But I guess it is a really wrong approach. So what is the way of doing this? Or is there a way?

Thank you for your time in advance.

Comment: If you put together a jsfiddle or plunker it would help in understanding what you want to do. Then we could help you fix the kinks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using angular.forEach() and applying the filter like `{{row.category | custom}}`

```
angular.module('angtestApp')
.filter('custom', function () {
    return function (input, $scope) {
        var name= null;
        angular.forEach($scope.categories, function(value, key){
            if(value.id == input) {
               name = value.name;
            }
        });
        return name;
    }
});
```